# How to use summernote in vueJS? Error:summernote is not a function

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, summernote

I am trying to use summernote in vueJS. Under Laravel framework. In blade.php document, I have set an id of summernot_div:

```
<input type="text" v-model="articleForChange.article_body" class="form-control" id="summernote_div" placeholder="Article Content">
```

Then, in the corresponding vueJS document, within the created() method:

```
$('#summernote_div').summernote({
  height: 300, // set editor height
  minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
  maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
  focus: true // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
});
console.log(summernote);
```

But the page just **response**:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function.

Is there **anything** I miss to do?

Comment: looks like you forgot to include the summernote library. are you using vueify? can you post the rest of the html?

Comment: You maybe did not call script tag to resolve summernote. try looking at your network tab in the console to see which js libraries and loaded and if summer note was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

Make sure that you added source. (CDN or Downloaded File)

```
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.4/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.4/summernote.js"></script>
```

Then wrap your javascript code in         `(function ($) { //your code gooes here })(jQuery);`

Like:

```
(function ($) {
$('#summernote_div').summernote({
  height: 300, // set editor height
  minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
  maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
  focus: true // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
});
})(jQuery);
```

This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the summernote init in the ready function instead of the created. As the [docs](http://vuejs.org/api/#created) state: DOM compilation has not been started, and the $el property will not be available yet.

Also make sure you have included the summernote plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem when I **first** added  file app.js (init components VueJS), and then the lib summernote file

```
<!-- Scripts app.js VueJS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
...
<!-- Summernote (Editor) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/components/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js') !!}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/components/summernote/dist/lang/summernote-en-EN.min.js') !!}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```